# I get a "db already exists with different case" exception but I am not trying to create a database

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, exception

I just want to add a word a database named "wordsDb" with a collection named "wordsCollection":

```js
    dbName = "wordsDb";
    collectionName = "wordsCollection";
    connectionUri = //... (secret)
    async add(word)
    {
        try {
            const client = new MongoClient(this.connectionUri);
            await client.connect();
            const database = client.db(this.dbName);
            const words = database.collection(this.collectionName);
            await words.insertOne(word); //error here
            await client.close();
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            throw e;
        }

    }
```

And I get a

> db already exists with different case already have: [wordsDB] trying to create [wordsDb]

exception.

I read about this exception [online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126378/db-already-exists-with-different-case-other) and it seems that it occurs when trying to create a database. But I am not trying to create any! Why does the exception occur then?

Comment: I think your connection uri has all the information so just try to const database = Client.db() and this will not try to create the database again.

Comment: @Sanjeev_gupta2812 tried. doesn't change the exception

Comment: Well In that you can check you database that you are using the same database with case sensitive thing. Try to change the name of the database and then try to access the same just make sure about the case sensitive thing.

Comment: MongoDB database names are _case-insensitive_: [Database naming](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#std-label-restrictions-on-db-names).

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB sees you're trying to access a database named `wordsDb`, but such database doesn't exist. The default action in such case would be to automatically create it, but MongoDB also sees that there's a database with the same name but a different casing.

The solution would be to either change `dbName` to `wordsDB`, rename the database you have in MongoDB Compass to `wordsDb`, or completely drop it.

Answer (score 0):

On MongoDB, there is no explicit command to create a database. If a database does not exist, MongoDB creates the database when you first store data for that database.

If you use the command `show dbs` and still not see the error database, try to drop it from the mongosh. Make sure that you have the right to drop db, e.g. userAdminAnyDatabase.